# How can I get the list of artifacts in my Maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, repository

Is there a Maven goal to list the artifacts that are stored in my local Maven repository?

Comment: Is the question about archetypes or artifacts?

Comment: No, it's about artifacts. I want to know which POMs I have in my repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any plugin doing that and, to be honest, I don't get the point. Maybe you could just use your OS file search feature to achieve your goal. If really you want to do this from Maven, then execute this command using the [maven-exec-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html). Another option would be to use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) if you can find an Ant task allowing to find files. But, as I said, I don't get the point of this.

Comment: What I want is to maintain an intermediate POM that includes all those artifacts. If I updated the repo I'd get the new list of artifacts, generate the POM and upload it.
The point is that my projects may use classes from a variety of jars and finding the apropiate one is not easy. Whith this, I only would need to use this POM.

Eclipse can find jars from class names, but only jars that are already in classpaths.

Comment: You should use a repository search engine instead: http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies