# How to read file from resources after deployed on Elastic Beanstalk in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have working code locally:

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/config");
File configFolder = new File(resource.getFile());
    for (File file : configFolder.listFiles()) {
        //working with files
    }
```

However it doesn't work on Elastic Beanstalk. My project structure is simple:

```
    /src
  /main
    /java
      /...
    /resources
      /static
        /config
           1.json
           2.json
           ...
      ...
```

I've tried to log what I could.

```
 LOG.info(Optional.ofNullable(
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/config"))
            .map(URL::toString)
            .orElse("null"));
```

Here what I receive:

```
jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/WEB-INF/classes!/static/config
```

So */static/config* folder should be present. But I get NPE here:

```
for (File file : configFolder.listFiles()) {
```

Should I work with files in other way? Does under EC2 instance there is a difference in file structure?

Comment: This is the difference between a resource in the local filesystem and a resource from inside a Jar - nothing to do with EB/AWS.

Comment: Thank you! Your hint helped me to get there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247669/read-directory-inside-jar-with-inputstreamreader
So there is no simple way to do it. :( That is really strange for me