# Zip a directory in src/main/resources within jar to outside location

Tags: java, maven, java-8, classloader, executable-jar

I am writing a java application, which contains a folder (with sub-folders) in src/main/resources (maven project) of the application. I want to zip the folder from src/main/resources and put it on a local path on the machine where this jar file is executed.

I can recursively read the files in the /src/main/resources using getClassLoader().getResource().getPath() in eclipse. But, when same code is executed from jar, I get FileNotFoundException.

I tried using getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() as suggested by some other similar questions in stackoverflow. But I can't retrieve the File objects of sub folders to add them as a ZipEntry.

Here's a snapshot of my pom.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>abc.def.ghi</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                      <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How do I retrieve a File object ( to recursively traverse and find list of files) in src/main/resources so that I can probably read individual files using getResourceAsStream() and write it to an external folder and then zip all of them from there ?

Is there any other approach to solve my issue ?

Comment: Do you want to do this as part of the build process or the execution (of the app) process? You can't do it (easily) duration the execution of the program

Comment: I want to do this in run time. Application should copy the directory from its jar to outside location and zip it.

Comment: Easiest way is to generate a text file with the contents of the directory at build time, this way you simply load the file, which provides a list of the resources. Another solution might be to pre-zip the resources (again at build time) and then simply extract it. Listing the contents of the Jar is at runtime is a lot of hassle and somewhat error prone

Comment: If you're hell bent on trying this - [this might be one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247669/read-directory-inside-jar-with-inputstreamreader/18247809#18247809)

Comment: You cannot use File when the resource is in a jar.  Have you considered moving these resources to their own artifact and let Maven do the heavy lifting?